# clear javascript console in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, console, google-chrome

I was wondering if I could clear up the console with some command..

`console.log()`, can print... is there a command to clear up console?..

I've tried to `console.log(console);` and got this functions below...

```
assert: function assert() { [native code] }
constructor: function Console() { [native code] }
count: function count() { [native code] }
debug: function debug() { [native code] }
dir: function dir() { [native code] }
dirxml: function dirxml() { [native code] }
error: function error() { [native code] }
group: function group() { [native code] }
groupEnd: function groupEnd() { [native code] }
info: function info() { [native code] }
log: function log() { [native code] }
markTimeline: function markTimeline() { [native code] }
profile: function profile() { [native code] }
profileEnd: function profileEnd() { [native code] }
time: function time() { [native code] }
timeEnd: function timeEnd() { [native code] }
trace: function trace() { [native code] }
warn: function warn() { [native code] }
__proto__: Object
```

[ I guess there's no way to clear up the console... but I wanted someone to say it to me... ]

Comment: Related posts - [How to clear Chrome console by shortcut keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5483451/465053) & [How to remove all recent console command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21149156/465053)

Answer (score 330, accepted):

> Update: `console.clear()` is available in all browsers

> Update: As of November 6, 2012, `console.clear()` is [now available](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/133614) in Chrome Canary.

---

If you type `clear()` into the console it clears it.

I don't think there is a way to programmatically do it, as it could be misused. (console is cleared by some web page, end user can't access error information)

one possible workaround:

in the console type `window.clear = clear`, then you'll be able to use clear in any script on your page.

Comment: duh... the javascript function is `clear()` ... it's the same thing.

Comment: @cobbal good point... but I don't get the 'it could be misused' part... can you share some knowledge about it?

Comment: A possible scenario where it would be annoying: some person develops a webpage, using the clear command and it makes its way into production code. You navigate to the page and something breaks. You can't figure out why since the console has been cleared by the page.

Comment: @chakrit try opening the url `javascript:alert(clear)`. it will say "clear is not defined"

Comment: @cobbal Indeed, my mistake. What I did binded a closure with `clear` from the console, so it works. Executing it outside of console doesn't.

Comment: productivity hint: click the 'clear' button in the status bar. same effect, saves you 7 keystrokes.

Comment: @schellmax Yeah, but you have to use the mouse. No fun.

Comment: console.clear() is now available in Chrome. Try it in Canary.

Comment: You can simply hit CTRL+L while cursor is focused in the console. All console output will be wiped.

Comment: Well, I was able to access clear problematically, this must have changed. To be honest, I think it should be accessible, I mean, what if you have a Single Page app, that allows people to opt-in to logging. When someone logs off you don't really want the next person to come a long and look at all the logging. console.clear() on log-off completion is a good fix to this problem.

Comment: Just a note, `clear()` doesn't work if you have checked "Preserve log upon navigation".

Comment: console object in [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consoleclear) browser. `if (console) { console.log('console command/object is defined ') }`  If IE Browser throws an error  console as undefined Object  then make changes F12 ► [Browser mode menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589500(v=vs.85).aspx) ► choose the Compatibility View option.           To Open [BrowserConsel](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Comment: I get the message `console.clear() was prevented due to 'Preserve log'`

Answer (score 135):

There's always the good ol' trick:

```
console.log("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
```

or a shorter variation of the above:

```
console.log('\n'.repeat('25'));
```

Not the most elegant solution, I know :) ... but works.

For me, I usually just print a long "-----" separator line to help make the logs easier to read.

Comment: When you can't use a scalpel, use an axe. +1

Comment: `console.log(new Array(24 + 1).join('\n')` does the same thing, but it's much shorter. :)

Comment: @Nyuszika7H If you're after conciseness: `console.log(Array(25).join('\n'))`. Calling the `Array` constructor without the `new` operator is spec'd to return an array.

Comment: Nice suggestions. I'm preparing a web presentation with console.info as "presenter notes" (following [Christian's advice](http://christianheilmann.com/2012/08/15/browsers-have-a-presenter-mode-console-info/)), and this is what I came up with, just in case I won't remember to assign `window.alert`:

`var hasClear = (typeof clear == 'function');
if(hasClear) clear();
console.info('bla');
if(!hasClear) console.log(Array(18).join('\n'));`

Comment: I would opt for the hard coded string, as it is more readable code. You can look at it for 1 second and know exactly what it does. And I guess there is a performance gain too.

Comment: This answer has the most ghetto:upvotes ratio I've ever seen on SO

Comment: @chakrit  You made my day!)

Comment: @chakrit Cool. But I get **undefined** above the blinking cursor :-D

Comment: `console.log('\n'.repeat(25))` without Array.join :)

Answer (score 44):

This seems to work just fine:

```
console.clear();
```

Answer (score 23):

If you use `console.clear()`, that seems to work in chrome. Note, it will output a "Console was cleared" message.

[image: I tested this by racking up a ton of Javascript errors.]

Note, I got an error right after clearing the console, so it doesn't disable the console, only clears it. Also, I have only tried this in chrome, so I dont know how cross-browser it is.

**EDIT:** I tested this in Chrome, IE, Firefox, and Opera. It works in Chrome, MSIE and Opera's default consoles, but not in Firefox's, however, it does work in Firebug.

Comment: This is the only suggestion that worked for me. Chrome.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Chrome Console Clear button]

If you want to just clear the console when debugging, you can simply click the "ban-circle"  `⃠`   button to clear console.log.

Alternatively just press **"Ctrl+L"** to clear the console using your keyboard.

Answer (score 14):

Chrome:

```
console._commandLineAPI.clear();
```

Safari:

```
console._inspectorCommandLineAPI.clear();
```

You can create your own variable, which works in both:

```
if (typeof console._commandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._commandLineAPI;
} else if (typeof console._inspectorCommandLineAPI !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console._inspectorCommandLineAPI;
} else if (typeof console.clear !== 'undefined') {
    console.API = console;
}
```

After that, you can simply use `console.API.clear()`.

Comment: This only works through the console itself on Chrome, in which case you can also just do `clear()` out of the box.

Answer (score 13):

you can use

```
console.clear();
```

if you are working with javascript coding.

else you can use `CTR+L` to clear cosole editor.

Answer (score 9):

`Press` `CTRL+L` Shortcut to clear `log`, even if you have ticked `Preserve log` option.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Used `clear()` for such a long time, yet I never thought to use Bash's notorious clear-terminal shortcut. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

On the Mac you can also use `⌘+K` just like in Terminal.

Comment: this is the most useful / practical solution of the thead.  thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Instead of typing command just press:

```
CLTRL + L
```

to clear chrome console

Comment: `clear()` and `console.clear()` returns an annoying `Console was cleared` and `undefined` messages, this command really clears it ... Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah I always use this, this is nice!

Answer (score 5):

```
console._inspectorCommandLineAPI.clear()
```

That is working

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'clear' of undefined`

Answer (score 5):

A handy compilation of multiple answers for clearing the console programmatically (from a script, *not* the console itself):

```
if(console._commandLineAPI && console._commandLineAPI.clear){
    console._commandLineAPI.clear();//clear in some safari versions
}else if(console._inspectorCommandLineAPI && console._inspectorCommandLineAPI.clear){
    console._inspectorCommandLineAPI.clear();//clear in some chrome versions
}else if(console.clear){
    console.clear();//clear in other chrome versions (maybe more browsers?)
}else{
    console.log(Array(100).join("\n"));//print 100 newlines if nothing else works
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On the Chrome console right click  with the mouse and  We have the option to clear the console

Answer (score 4):

I use the following to alias `cls` when debugging locally in Chrome (enter the following JavaScript into the console):

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'cls', {
    get: function () {
        return console.clear();
    }
});
```

now entering `cls` in the console will clear the console.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> while focusing the console input.

Firefox - `clear()` in console input.

Internet Explorer - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> while focusing the console input.

Edge - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> while focusing the console input.

Have a good day!

Answer (score 3):

Based on Cobbal's *answer*, here's what I did:

In my `JavaScript` I put the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if(window.clear) {
    window.clear();
    console.log("this is highly repeated code");
  }
}, 10);
```

The conditional code won't run until you ASSIGN window.clear (meaning your log is empty until you do so). **IN THE DEBUG CONSOLE TYPE:**

```
window.clear = clear;
```

## Violà - a log that clears itself.

*Mac OS 10.6.8 - Chrome 15.0.874.106*

Answer (score 3):

On **MacOS**:

1. Chrome - <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
2. Safari - <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
3. Firefox - No shortcut

On **Linux**:

1. Chrome - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
2. Firefox - No shortcut

On **Windows**:

1. Chrome - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
2. IE - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
3. Edge - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
4. Firefox - No shortcut

To make it work in Firefox, `userscripts` can be used. Download `GreaseMonkey` extension for FF.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
    if(event.metaKey && event.which==75) //CMD+K
    {
        console.clear();
    }
});
```

In the script, update the metadata with the value, `//@include  *://*/*`, to make it run on every pages. It will work only when the focus is on the page. It's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is no longer available due to 'security issues'.

`console.log(console)` from code gives:

```
Console
memory: MemoryInfo
profiles: Array[0]
__proto__: Console
```

From outside of code, _commandLineAPI is available. Kind of annoying because sometimes I want to just log and not see the old output.

Comment: Don't forget to follow the prototype chain when determining what methods are available on an object :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to add to this, as it's a search that came out top on google..

When using ExtJS / Javascript I insert this and the console is cleared out - unless there is an error..

```
console.log('\033[2J');
```

I'm more than likely way off course, but this is how I clear the console for each page load/refresh.

Comment: You should restructure the language to make this a more appropriate answer.