# How to clear Chrome console by shortcut keys?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to clear the Console tab in Chrome developer tools inside the Chrome browser.  I know that their is an button for that but what's the shortcut keys for doing that?

Are their anywhere cheatsheet for chrome developer tool or chrome shortcuts?

Comment: Related posts - [clear javascript console in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3011600/465053) & [How to remove all recent console command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21149156/465053)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to clear the chrome-dev-console on Windows/Linux and <kbd>Cmd + K</kbd> on Mac.

Comment: That's control + lowercase-L (I thought maybe it was the capital i character)

Comment: And how to make a CTRL+L in the browser when the dev console is open ? :/

Comment: `Cmd + K` on Mac

Comment: FYI (for Mac users) this answer should mention it's Cmd+K on Mac and include this link: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/shortcuts.html

Comment: I added the suggestion for Mac and clarified the other is for Win/Linux.

Comment: not working on mac
with caps lock on also not working

Answer (score 13):

The list of keyboard shortcuts for Chrome Developer Tools is at: http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/shortcuts.html.

For clearing the console log, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>. Unfortunately, it appears the log needs to be in focus (clicked on) for the keyboard command to work.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut to focus on the console is Ctrl + ` (i.e. <ctrl> with <backquote>). see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts.

Comment: This one does not work for me, It increases the panels percentage size

Answer (score 9):

Keyboard shortcuts

```
Ctrl + L or Cmd + L
```

Command line

```
clear()
```

Here's a cheatsheet for more shortcut keys: http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/

Comment: In Chrome Canary, they've added console.clear() ... version > 25.

Answer (score 5):

I do not know why, but on my Mac (OS X El Capitan v10, Google Chrome v40) shortcuts mentioned above <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> **do NOT clear** the Console log.

**But <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> perfectly works !!!** 
*Before using this shortcut make sure that the console is active!*

**So my solution for Macs is: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> !!!**

Comment: `Cmd + k` also clears the scrollback buffer in iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

It is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for Firefox console.

Comment: I'd open new question re: Firefox dev tools and port your answer to that

Answer (score 1):

I found a different shortcut by accident. Maybe it is doing something else.
Press Spacebar to clear the console in chrome devtools. It works too. ;)

NB: I am using ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS