# What is the difference between console.clear() and ctrl+L in browser console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser, console

I am a beginner in web.
I am using `chrome` for debugging,

- ctrl+l clears the console screen
- console.clear just returns the following message

*Console was cleared*

What is the difference between these two,whether they are for same purpose or different purpose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483451/how-to-clear-chrome-console-by-shortcut-keys/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`console.clear()` and `ctrl+l` both are doing the same work and ctrl+l is a shortcut for clearing the console.

`control.clear()` clears the console screen when [preserve log](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-ui?hl=en) option is unchecked.