# How to empty console logs in webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, console, webkit

Is there a way to empty the console in webkit? I have a function displaying debug data in the console, but it gets very unreadable because of the number of lines, is there a simple way to clear the console?

When I log the console itself, I only see these methods:

```
assert: function assert() {
count: function count() {
debug: function debug() {
dir: function dir() {
dirxml: function dirxml() {
error: function error() {
group: function group() {
groupCollapsed: function groupCollapsed() {
groupEnd: function groupEnd() {
info: function info() {
log: function log() {
markTimeline: function markTimeline() {
profile: function profile() {
profileEnd: function profileEnd() {
time: function time() {
timeEnd: function timeEnd() {
timeStamp: function timeStamp() {
trace: function trace() {
warn: function warn() {
```

any idea? without reloading the page obviously...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `clear()` to clear the console but if you want it programmatically you need to work around. There is answer in stackoverflow - [clear javascript console in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome).

I hope this helps!

Comment: strange stack overflow didn't pointed me to this question as it is identical, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As a non-programmatic solution, you can just click the "clear" button:

[image]