# js/clear throws an error when called from repl

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I am using reagent and am connected to the browser using weasel (tenzing template using boot). In my browser (chrome) console I am able to call `clear()` and it works.

However when I type (js/clear) in my cider repl, it throws an error -

ReferenceError: clear is not defined

I am however able to run (js/alert "Hello") without any problems. Any ideas what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(.clear js/console)
(.log js/console "asdasd")
```

Worked in my Figwheel REPL. You should try Figwheel, btw: https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel

In case you ask "why" but not "how", this question should `clear` the situation: [clear javascript console in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

When you're typing `clear()` into the console you're not using the [Console API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api), but the [Command Line API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api).

It's not possible to call this function from javascript:

> This API complements the Console API, the Command Line API is only
>   available from within the console itself.

Note that: Some are available in both. Such as `console.dir` or `console.clear` which you can call with `(.clear js/console)`.