# How do I clear Javascript console and delete everything stored in memory?

Tags: javascript

In the Developer Tools' Console in Chrome, I want to be able to completely delete all variables stored in memory.

For example:

```
var x = 8;
x // 8
clear()
x // not found, x is not defined
```

instead every time I try to do a variation of `clear()` or `console.clear()`, the variables still exist in memory and I get:

```
var x = 8;
x // 8
clear()
x // 8
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome console clear assignment and variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270829/chrome-console-clear-assignment-and-variables)

Comment: You mean clearing the memory of all the recently typed and executed stuff, right? This might be what you are looking for, but the answer is not as simple as executing a command: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149275/1760313

Comment: @Tom something close to that, but is there nothing similar to a `consoleHistory.delete()` command? instead of going through the console GUI to do all that

Comment: or a `delete all` command?

Comment: No, there is `localstorage.removeItem(key)`, but you can't use that to remove the `consoleHistory` key which belongs to another domain (or in this case, the dev tools domain). It would be a security risk if you could in normal situations, obviously the dev tools within the Console tab would be an exception, but that's not been taken into account.

Comment: You could however right click and click `Clear console history`. It's way faster.

Comment: Its a shame that `clear console history` isn't available in firefox dev tools 112

Comment: Reload the browser.

Answer (score 3):

Clearing the console history is easy, right click on the Console window and select the "Clear console history" option from the context menu.

Golden rule: **You cannot delete anything declared with var**

If you want to hack your way through cleaning up the global scope you could identify what you've added by exploring the keys of the window object.

```
Object.keys(window)
```

Make a note of the keys you want to remove and then try to delete them:

```
['a', 'x'].map(prop => delete window[prop]);
```

Delete will try to remove the property from the window object and returns a boolean result, so you might end up with a response like

```
[true, false]
```

This indicates the first item was deleted but unfortunately the second was not.

In your case you could assign the x variable to null so it is marked for garbage collection but when will the window object go out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing below issue with const variables declared within snippet when i tried to run the snippet multiple times without refreshing the page.

```
 SyntaxError: Identifier 'MY_CONST_VARIABLE' has already been declared
```

If you have created variable within console or snippet and want to clear just those variables but not the variables created by js file added to your html page using script tag, then you can just refresh the browser page and all variables created by you using "console and snippet" will get removed.

Answer (score -2):

There [clear function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) just removes the text from the console.

There is no mechanism to remove all existing variables or clearing the cache from JS.

Open the Network tab and tick "Disable cache" then refresh the page to do that.

Comment: You don't need to disable the cache to reset the Javascript environment.

Comment: @duskwuff — True, but the OP asked how to empty the cache.