# How can I clear the console (Javascript) in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

The clear() command and the Clear button just clear the screen, but any constants and variables remain, causing problems when trying to do simple tests.  Do I need to restart the application every time?

Comment: `but any constants and variables remain` what does this mean? The console doesn't make variables, which is why I am confused?

Comment: @AlGoreRhythm He probably wants to wipe variables that were defined in console. Like when you type: `var a = 10`, then a lives in global scope.

Comment: And yes, I think you need to restart your app. @NickNearPhila

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270829/chrome-console-clear-assignment-and-variables

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "clear" the variables set in console. They do represent current state of your application, so yes, you need to restart the application to reset this state.

You will need to write a procedure that puts variables in their original state. Or use local variables that perish once a procedure is over.