# how to clear console data without refreshing the page in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, console

I am reading an ebook, which is about ReactJs,I want to run commands in the same page console but if redeclare the same variable it showing me **variable has already been declared**
**for ex:-**

```
var pizza = true
pizza = false
console.log(pizza)
```

when i declarce const it show's me

```
const pizza = true
pizza = false
```

error:-

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'pizza' has already been declared**

I searched and used these commands but it is not working

```
CLTRL + L
```

`console.clear()`;

```
window.clear = clear

clear()
```

**Can anyone can tell me how to refresh console without refreshing the page**

Comment: @zulqarnain See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42238936/5846045

Answer (score 1):

Constants are read-only, therefore the value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared.

For more details refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: I just want to refresh the console not assigning the value into the const then only i can declare const new variable

Comment: Right click on Log message and Clear console?

Comment: nope, it's not about clearing console, how to clear the whole window.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you are really implying :|

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code is this related?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap code into function. When the function ends varibles are deallocated.

```
(function() {
    //your code here
})();
```

Comment: it's too lengthy process and further, it becomes complex aslo

Answer (score 0):

You can clear console with a "stop / danger button" on left top of the console. [here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwZTN.png)

and about `CTRL + L` is working for me.

Comment: [ Maybe this can help you ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149156/how-to-remove-all-recent-console-command)