# Clear console with command

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, command

Like this is my console currently with lots of line in it

[image]

Is there any javascript or jquery command with which i can clear the console.

> I don't want to hit clear button with mouse. Only a code command is required.

Comment: Solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.clear();
```

You can use this code in your scripts. Read more about [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console).

> Note that in Google Chrome, console.clear() has no effect if the user
>   has selected "Preserve log upon navigation" in the settings.

**Update**: As noticed @evolutionxbox you can use just `clear()` to do that. You'll get the same result.

You can also clear console in the web browsers with keyboard shortcuts:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Clear console in Firebug: <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: is it supported in all browsers??

Comment: Yes, It is (most of modern browsers support `console.clear()` and `clear()`)

Comment: Works perfectly with React Native 0.63.3

Answer (score 3):

You can use `console.clear()`, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either below commands

```
 clear()
 console.clear()
 window.clear()
```

OR

`CTRL` + `L` as Shortcut to clear Developer Console.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal Maybe. I tested with Chrome Cuz OP's Screenshot is from Chrome.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal It's working. My Chrome version is  50.0.2661.94

Answer (score 2):

A common convention for all browsers is

```
clear()
```

for chrome and some other webkit based browsers you can also use

```
console.clear()
```