# Refresh console log data without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, logging, console

I have a site that is constantly refreshing multiple tables on a page, sourcing them for external php files. This is to give the perception of automatically updating tables of job data.

But each of these tables is refreshing every 2 seconds, which you don't notice but the browser definitely notices because it becomes slow after a while of sitting on the same page.

Because I didn't set up the foundations of the website, I'm now looking into a way to avoid the browser becoming so laggy when staying on a page for an extended period of time, mostly because I want to have a page constantly open on our server.

Is there any way to do this through javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clear javascript console in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can meta tag in your html page. Example below is set as 5 seconds.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without refreshing the page itself?