# How clear previous console.log in each react rendering?

Tags: reactjs, console.log

When I make a change in my React app, it renders and shows my `console.log()`, but the previous `console.logs()` are not cleared automatically. This can be confusing. The app has been refreshed, but the console has not been cleared.

How do I change setting to clear previous `console.log()` each time, before it is rendered? I want to see only last `console.log()` in browser console. This should be done by React itself and not me manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clear javascript console in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011600/clear-javascript-console-in-google-chrome) (Using this inside the relevant lifecycle method, depending on class/functional components, should do it)

Comment: @DBS No! It is relative to react or linter or webpack or package.json or etc. For example, in Angular, every thing is ok!

Comment: This depends on the hot reloader configuration you're using. You might be able to hook into a "hot reload done" event and call `console.clear()` there.

Comment: put a console.clear() to your App file :)

Comment: @AKX How should I do this? In my opinion, this solution can be the right solution. I want to a hot reload like page refreshing.

Comment: @halilcakar I know about console.clear(), but it is not my answer. This should not be done manually. React refreshes the page, so it should clear the console as well.

Comment: Well I got your point and it's easier putting a `console.clear()` to your app instead trying to find out about hot reload it's a choice obv. have it your way :)

Comment: @halilcakar Thanks so much :) but this is a tedious way to write console.clear() every time! A professional coder does not do this. This problem must be solved systematically by react, like angular.

Comment: @Saeedsdns As said, it depends on the hot reloader configuration. You're just saying you're using React; you could be using CRA, Vite, Rollup, a custom Webpack configuration, ...